# echo o/p from crontab

Tags: linux, bash

If my crontab had the entry

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
12 16 5 6 7 echo "echo from cron"
```

where would the output of echo go ?

I don't see it on my shell's stout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gets sent to the local mailbox of the user the script runs under.

Answer (score 1):

`cron` emails the output of the command to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want me to give you the fish:

$MAILTO is who gets mailed the output of each command. But, i usually redirect the out and err to files.

If you want me to teach you fishing: Go to the *cron man page* and search for *output*

Comment: Usually to files? What platform? Just curious, never seen that.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly redirect the output to a file, if you don't want to rely on `mail`